How to prove partial correctness of a program with Hoare Logic?
I am working on a problem where I need to prove the partial correctness of the following program using Hoare logic:
z = x;
while (z > 1) {
    z = z - 2;
}

Problem Description
This program determines whether the input x is
even or odd. Use Hoare logic and prove partial correctness of the program given these pre- and post-conditions. State all proof obligations and justify that they are correct. (However, you do not need to provide any formal proof in ND for them to be correct.)
The correctness is specified using the following
preconditions and postconditions:
Precondition:
⟨x = x₀ ∧ x ≥ 0⟩
Postcondition:
⦇(∃n(x₀ = 2n) ∧ z = 0) ∨ (∃n(x₀ = 2n + 1) ∧ z = 1)⦈
Any help with how to use Hoare logic to prove partial correctness of the program given these pre- and post-conditions, constructing the loop invariant, breaking down the proof obligations, or understanding how to justify the steps would be greatly appreciated!
My understanding so far is that x=x₀ ∧ x ≥ 0 means x₀ is the initial value of x, and x is non−negative at the start.  (∃ n (x₀=2 n ) ∧ z=0 ) ∨ (∃ n (x₀=2 n+1 ) ∧ z=1 ) means that z=0 if x₀ is even and z=1 if x₀  is odd.
